# Comparing content in two csv files

Tags: python, csv

So I have two csv files.  `Book1.csv` has more data than `similarities.csv` so I want to pull out the rows in `Book1.csv` that **do not** occur in `similarities.csv` Here's what I have so far

```
    with open('Book1.csv', 'rb') as csvMasterForDiff:
        with open('similarities.csv', 'rb') as csvSlaveForDiff:
            masterReaderDiff = csv.reader(csvMasterForDiff)
            slaveReaderDiff = csv.reader(csvSlaveForDiff)        

            testNotInCount = 0
            testInCount = 0
            for row in masterReaderDiff:
                if row not in slaveReaderDiff:
                    testNotInCount = testNotInCount + 1
                else :
                    testInCount = testInCount + 1


print('Not in file: '+ str(testNotInCount))
print('Exists in file: '+ str(testInCount))
```

However, the results are

```
Not in file: 2093
Exists in file: 0
```

I know this is incorrect because at least the first 16 entries in `Book1.csv` do not exist in `similarities.csv` not all of them.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `csv.reader` object is an *iterator*, which means you can only iterate through it **once**. You should be using lists/sets for containment checking, e.g.:

```
slave_rows = set(slaveReaderDiff)

for row in masterReaderDiff:
    if row not in slave_rows:
        testNotInCount += 1
    else:
        testInCount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting it into `sets`, you can do a lot of `set` related & helpful operation without writing much of a code.

```
slave_rows = set(slaveReaderDiff)
master_rows = set(masterReaderDiff)

master_minus_slave_rows = master_rows - slave_rows
common_rows = master_rows & slave_rows

print('Not in file: '+ str(len(master_minus_slave_rows)))
print('Exists in file: '+ str(len(common_rows)))
```

Here are various [set operations](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) that you can do.